# jQuery pop up window only opens on second click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
/* action dropdown*/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".action-toggler").click(function(ev){
    jQuery(this).children(".action-dropdown").toggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  jQuery("body").click(function(){
    jQuery(".action-dropdown").hide();
  });
});

/* modle-popup*/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".popup-button").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery("body").addClass("sitemodal-open");
    jQuery(".sitemodal").addClass("in");
  });

  jQuery('.sitemodal .sitemodal-dialog').click(function($){
    $.stopPropagation();
  });

  jQuery(".close-popup ,.sitemodal").click(function(){
    jQuery("body").removeClass("sitemodal-open");
    jQuery(".sitemodal").removeClass("in");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <span class="msg-icon action-toggler" style="float:right;">
    <img src="images/dots.png" ></img>
    <ul class="action-dropdown">        
      <li>
        <a class="popup-button" data-target="#delete-popup" >Delete</a>
        <!-- siteModal content-->
        <div class="sitemodal fade" id="reply-popup">
         <div class="sitemodal-dialog">
            <div class="sitemodal-content">
              <div class="sitemodal-header">
                <h4 class="sitemodal-title">Delete</h4>
             </div>
            <hr style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom:2px;">
           <div class="sitemodal-body" style="padding: 16px 0;">
              <h4 class="sitemodal-title" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 400;">Are you sure you want to delete this message?</h4>
              <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="Post" action="" name="" onsubmit="">
                <hr style="margin-top: 16px;margin-bottom:2px;">
              <div class="sitemodal-footer" style="display: flex;margin-bottom: -8px;">
                    //php code here
                 </div>
              </form>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>       
  </span>
```

I have a drop down menu which contains a "delete" option when clicked it shows a pop up window

the problem that i am having is that when the "delete" option is clicked nothing happens first time but when clicked second time the pop up shows up

tried to trigger drop down window from the "model-pop" but didn't work

trid to remove the pop-up window outside of the `</ul>` but didnt work

can you please give me a hint or i am getting wrong at the least

removed some unrelated code to be easier to read

Comment: Can you provide the code in a manner that shows visibly for us to make a Snippet from?

Comment: i removed the code in the body and added it the snippet,is ok now ?

Comment: could it be because of `jQuery(document).ready` ??? did you tried with `<div onclick="" ` instead ?

Comment: can you please explain use case once, so what I am thinking here is, you want to launch a modal on click of delete, and close it on click of close button and on body click as well but outside the modal? that's it?